# Python Django RegExp error

Tags: python, regex, django, error-handling

I'm designing a search for my blog. This is my stop words list:

```
STOP_WORDS = r"""\b(a|about|above|across...)\b"""
```

I keep getting this traceback:

```
Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern
```

Does anyone know why? How should I rewrite:

```
stop_word_list = re.compile(STOP_WORDS_RE, re.IGNORECASE)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show this code, but presumably you have

```
STOP_WORDS_RE = re.compile(STOP_WORDS)
```

somewhere.

You want to pass `re.IGNORECASE` to `re.compile` with the regex *string*, `STOP_WORDS` in your case. So:

```
# *not* STOP_WORDS_RE!
stop_word_list = re.compile(STOP_WORDS, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass `re.IGNORECASE` when you compile it, you pass it when you **use** it. See the [source for `re.compile`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1777df2ce50d/Lib/re.py#l260).